# onChange replace img src with dropdown title not value

Tags: javascript, image, onchange

I have a set of radio buttons that work when clicked where it will change the image based on the click.

Now I want to change an image based on the dropdown box selection.  Here is part of my script.  Is using "title" not proper?

**Also, it doesn't feel right that I have a function within a function... I'm just trying to figure out if I even need the `.change(function () {` part if it's already being triggered by the `select's onchange`?  I tried with and without and it's still not replacing the image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doCalc(){
    var roomX = $('#room_str').val();
    var otherroomX = $('#other_room').val();
    var qtyX = $('#qty_str').val();
    // etc. etc..
    // below is code that pertains to what i'm trying to do 

    var imgFldr2 = '/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/';
    var imagename = $('#laserlite_color option:selected').attr('title');
    $('#valance-colors-placeholder img').attr('src', imgFldr2 + imagename); 
    });
    // more code
```

and the dropdown box...

```
<select name="laserlite_color" id="laserlite_color" onchange="doCalc();">
    <option value="Gold 301" title="Gold-301.jpg">Gold</option>
    <option value="Chrome 303" title="Chrome-301.jpg">Chrome</option>
    <option value="Light Oak 304" title="Light-Oak-304.jpg">Light Oak</option>
    <option value="Dark Walnut 302" title="Dark-Walnut-302.jpg">Dark Walnut</option>
    <option value="White 307" title="White-307.jpg">White</option>
    <option value="Silk 630" title="Silk-630.jpg">Silk</option>
    <option value="Lilac 688" title="Lilac-688.jpg">Lilac</option>
    <option value="Blush 672" title="Blush-672.jpg">Blush</option>
    <option value="Sage 655" title="Sage-655.jpg">Sage</option>
    <option value="Denim 641" title="Denim-641.jpg">Denim</option>
    <option value="Black Satin 684" title="Black-Satin-684.jpg">Black Satin</option>
</select><br>

<div id="valance-colors-placeholder"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Gold-301.jpg"></div>
```

EDIT:  I've updated my code with part of Nick's code below.  I just want to explain that on this website I remember programmer's saying to use `alert('whatever variable you need to see returned here');` and that helps with seeing what part of your code is and isn't working properly.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you're doing here is adding an onchange event handler each time someone changes the select. Beyond that, the event handler doesn't do what you think it should because 'this' is not what you think it is. When you attempt to set the image based on "this.title", that's probably either undefined or an empty string, because "this" refers to the select tag, not the selected option.

That aside, what I would recommend is removing the onchange attribute on the select in html, and just let jQuery do what it's good at in your script tag:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('#laserlite_color').change(function () {
        var roomX = $('#room_str').val();
        // ... the rest of what you're doing in doCalc ...
        var imgFldr2 = '/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/';
        var filename = $('#laserlite_color option:selected').attr('title');
        $('#valance-colors-placeholder img').attr('src', imgFldr2 + filename);
    });
});
```

As for (ab)using the title attribute, you might consider that there should be a strict relationship between the value of the option and the filename. If that is the case, then you can use jQuery's val() on the select tag. Luckily, it appears there is a one-to-one mapping from the value to the image file. Try this for the filename line, instead:

```
var filename = $('#laserlite_color').val().replace(' ', '-') + '.jpg';
```

Comment: I took part of your code and it worked.  I had to use the doCalc() because it was triggering lots of other code using AJAX and instant pricing calculations.  I basically snipped out lines 5,6,7 from your code and pasted into my doCalc() function.  Hopefully that is proper and it is working!!!  I'll update my first post above with your answer.  Lastly, your final note is awesome.  I didn't even think of basic replace option for naming strict relationships like that.

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

**HLML**

```
<select name="laserlite_color" id="laserlite_color"  onchange="doCalc(this);">
```

**Javascript**

```
function doCalc(selectobj) {
        var value1 = selectobj[selectobj.selectedIndex].value
        var text1 = selectobj[selectobj.selectedIndex].text
       //your code
       //your code
       //your code
         $('#valance-colors-placeholder img').attr('src', imgFldr + value1);
    }
```

need to send the value of the event to catch it in your JavaScript function

Answer (score 1):

You were referencing the `select` title which does not exist and was returning empty string. It is the options that has the title attribute. If the onchange is not called you might need to put it in `$(document).ready(...)`

```
$('#laserlite_color').change(function () {
      var title = this.options[this.selectedIndex].title;
      $('#valance-colors-placeholder img').attr('src', imgFldr+title); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the select option you shoud add in html part**

```
<select name="number" id="course" style="width:158px;" onchange="getImage(this)">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                   <option value= 1 > Image1 </option>
                    <option value= 2 > Image2 </option>
                    </select>
```

**Create seperate css for diaplaying the image**

```
<img id="imgt" style="width:750px; height: 475px;"/></div>
```

**Here is the script**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function getImage(v) {
                var num = v.value;                
                if (num == 1) {
                    document.getElementById("imgt").setAttribute("src", "images/image1.png");
                }
                else  (num == 2) {
                    document.getElementById("imgt").setAttribute("src", "images/image2.png");
                }
                }
        </script>
```